# Getting errors while installing streamlit usin pip in

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, data-science, streamlit

I am getting the following error while installing streamlit using pip.

How do i fix this.

Is there an alternative way i can download streamlit?

I deleted a few lines of code due to ease of understanding

```py
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp98zgcj_w'
           cwd: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-
      copying pyarrow\tests\parquet\test_parquet_writer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyarrow\tests\parquet
      running build_ext
      creating C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8d7399fc\pyarrow_54eefc0597024fa083b65739386c1def\build\temp.win32-3.8
      Traceback (most recent call last):

          cmd_obj.run()
        File "setup.py", line 92, in run
          self._run_cmake()
        File "setup.py", line 280, in _run_cmake
          raise RuntimeError('Not supported on 32-bit Windows')
      RuntimeError: Not supported on 32-bit Windows
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
    Failed to build pyarrow
    ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on this error message you're using 32-bit Python?

Pyarrow only works for 64 bit operating systems and, therefore, Streamlit became 64 bit dependant after we added this as a dependancy in Streamlit version 0.63!

Is 32 over 64 bit intentional? If not, your hardware system is most likely 64-bit (if it was made in the last 10 years), and switching to 64-bit Python should resolve the error message.

Marisa